# How to add both date and space to a filename

Tags: bash, shell, date, touch

If I execute `touch $(date '+%F %T')`, I expect one file whose filename comprises the date and time to be created; but instead two files are created: one whose name is the date, and the other whose name is the time:

```
$ touch $(date '+%F %T')
$ ls -1
12:39:26
2019-03-05
```

Why is this, and how can I create a file named `2019-03-05 12:39:26` instead, without using an underscore instead of a space?

Comment: If you run `date '+%F %T'` you will see you have two strings. This is like calling `touch 12:39:26 2019-03-05`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes:

```
touch "$(date '+%F %T')"
```

Related:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)